# IntelliJ IDEA intention actions on Mac with Windows keyboard

Tags: macos, intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

In my Java source code file, there is a return statement, but the method is `void`:

```
public void a() {
    return "x";
}
```

IntelliJ IDEA shows a red line under `return "x";`.

I now want to use the "Show Intention Actions" action, to fix this issue. By globally searching for that action, I found out, that the shortcut for to do so is ⌥⏎ (on my Mac, using Mac OS X 10.5+ keymap), in words:

<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

Since I use a Windows keyboard, I expected this shortcut to be for me:

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

However, this does not trigger anything in IntelliJ IDEA.

How do I show the intention actions on a Mac with a Windows keyboard?

Comment: Are you sure that `alt` maps to `option` on your Windows keyboard? Try adding a new keyboard shortcut and see how IDE recognizes this combination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Mac, <kbd>option</kbd> is only mapped to <kbd>alt</kbd> in *some* input methods. Choosing `British` input method works on my machine, choosing `Unicode Hex Input` fails.